# Remove Section Numbering for Abstract in APA6

Tags: sectioning, apa-style, abstract, apa6

I am writing a paper in an APA6 class document. I would like to number the sections which I did with `\setcounter{3}`. 
However, I would not like to have my abstract numbered but could of course not use the `*` option here.

Any suggestions very welcome!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

The Abstract:

```
\abstract{\textit{Background:} text.\\ 
\textit{Methods:} text.\\ 
\textit{Results:} text.\\ \textit{Conclusion:} text. 
\keywords{Linalool, Anti-Oxidant, Oxidative Stress, Glutamate.}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

Comment: Aren't you using `\abstract{write abstract here}` for the abstract? That isn't numbered.

Comment: Call me stupid, but `\section*{Lorem}` works for me

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes I am but it is numbered as first section of my thesis.

Comment: @moewe for the sections and subsections "*" works just fine. Not for the abstract though.

Comment: I do *not* get numbering when using `\abstract`, can you make a complete example showing how you make your abstract, instead of just the preamble?

Comment: @CesiumNotch Why don't you give one mwe?

Comment: \abstract{\textit{Background:}
text.\\
\textit{Methods:}
text.\\
\textit{Results:}
text.\\
\textit{Conclusion:}
text.
\keywords{Linalool, Anti-Oxidant, Oxidative Stress, Glutamate.}}

Comment: So you want to write `\abstract*`?

Comment: OK, I understand what you did know, but it would have a bit clearer if you made a complete example. While you do mention it (sort of) in the text, in the code you have not included the crucial `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes you are right. Sorry I forgot that I had one try where I put it behind the abstract and left it there.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `\setcounter` after `\maketitle`? And by "complete example" I mean a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228), that is the smallest complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem. Not all questions require one (some do), but it usually makes it a lot easier to understand what is going on, which makes it a lot easier for us to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Please consider pasting *proper* minimal examples (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)) in the future. Even if your question can be understood without one, an MWE makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing and that we can test the solution we come up with in an environment that is useful to you. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864

Answer (score 2):

Issue

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {\section*{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {}{\typeout{Failed to patch abstract.}}
```

*before* you load `hyperref`. This makes the abstract use `\section*` instead of `\section`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {\section*{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {}{\typeout{Failed to patch abstract.}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\author{Anne Elk}
\title{On the Theory of Brontosauruses}
\shorttitle{Brontosauruses}

\abstract{\blindduck}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Lorem}
\blindduck
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you must patch `\abstract` after loading `hyperref` you need to patch `\HyOrg@maketitle` instead. Don't forget the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` in that case.

---

Another solution would be to only set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` after `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\author{Anne Elk}
\title{On the Theory of Brontosauruses}
\shorttitle{Brontosauruses}

\abstract{\blindduck}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\section*{Lorem}
\blindduck
\duckument
\end{document}
```